# Qt5 with CMake: how to find qt translations dir?

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization, cmake, qt5

I am currently working on porting my application to Qt5. I use CMake as my build system.
With Qt4, I used QT_TRANSLATIONS_DIR variable to copy precompiled Qt translations to the target directory. However, Qt5 does not define any of these specific variables. I know the command

```
qmake -query QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS
```

gives me correct path to where Qt translations are installed on my system. I would like to use it, but now I dont know how to get the qmake executable path. I tried to use

```
Qt5Core_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE
```

variable, but it gives me "Qt5::qmake", which is not a correct executable.

What I would like to see is a list of Qt each target's properties to know how I can get specific variables, but I could not find anything like that on the internet. CMake documentation does not answer my questions.

How can I get path of qt translations with cmake and qt5?
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I found the solution.
To get the qmake executable location for currect Qt prefix, you can use

```
get_target_property (QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE Qt5::qmake IMPORTED_LOCATION)
```

However, I find it weird that it is nowhere to be found in the documentation.

Comment: To expand on this a bit... `QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE` is the variable that the resulting full `<path-to>/qmake` path will be stored in.  Additionally, `Qt5::qmake` can optionally be replaced with `${Qt5Core_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE}`, which is set up inside `Qt5CoreConfigExtras.cmake`